# Calculate partition function of 1D quantum Heisenberg models?

Tags: condensed-matter, computational-physics, spin-models, integrable-systems, spin-chains

For the 1D Quantum Heisenberg Spin Model:

$\displaystyle {\hat H = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{N} (J_x \sigma_j^x \sigma_{j+1}^x + J_y \sigma_j^y \sigma_{j+1}^y + J_z \sigma_j^z \sigma_{j+1}^z + h\sigma_j^{z})}$

Where ${\sigma_{j}^x}, {\sigma_{j}^y}, {\sigma_{j}^z}$ are pauli matrices.

Are there any open source library to calculate its partition functions for any number of spins and $J$ ? (prefer in Python, C or C++).

Above expression is only for nearest neighbor interaction. We are also interested in interactions between any spin.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any publicly available code but it seems hardly necessary, this system is very easy to implement. Here is some Mathematica code that I wrote in a couple of minutes:

```
Σ[a_][1, 1] := PauliMatrix[a];
Σ[a_][n_, i_] /; 1 <= i < n := KroneckerProduct[Σ[a][n - 1, i], IdentityMatrix[2]];
Σ[a_][n_, n_] := KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2^(n - 1)], PauliMatrix[a]];

With[{n = 4},
    -1/2 Sum[jx Σ[1][n, j].Σ[1][n, Mod[j, n] + 1] + jy Σ[2][n, j].Σ[2][n, Mod[j, n] + 1] + jz Σ[3][n, j].Σ[3][n, Mod[j, n] + 1] + h Σ[3][n, j], {j, 1, n}]
]
```

You can easily compute the spectrum of $H$ numerically for small $n$. For example take $n=8$ and $h=0$, and work in units where $J_x=1$. Then, the gap of the system as a function of $J_y,J_z$ is obtained via

```
Flatten[Table[{jy, jz, #[[2]] - #[[1]] &@Sort[Eigenvalues[%]]}, {jy, 0, 2, .01}, {jz, 0, 2, .01}], 1]
ListDensityPlot[%, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"jy", "jz"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

so we clearly see transitions across points and lines of enhanced symmetry, $J_y=1$ and $J_z=1$.

The partition function is also very easy to evaluate, you just use `Tr[MatrixExp[-β H]]`.

For larger $n$ it becomes very costly to construct (let alone, diagonalize) the Hamiltonian so you need to be cleverer. The code above has a lot of room for improvement but in the end, if you want really large $n$, there are no exact methods available, you need approximations (some smart truncation, a statistical approach, or even using hardware specifically designed for such calculations...)

If you insist on using C/python/etc you'll have to translate the code above to your preferred language. It should be self-explanatory so I am sure you will succeed.

Comment: Doesn't this scale exponentially in $n$?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch It very much does, indeed. Not as much as a problem with the algorithm itself: the Hilbert space of the theory is $2^n$ dimensional. Hence, my second-to-last paragraph: it is not feasible to solve the problem exactly (with my code, or in any other way) unless $n$ is relatively small (or you are capable of making a quantum computer, with a large number of qubits, of course)

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer. I can work with the Mathematica code. In your code, why do we need Mod[j, n] ?Plus, what do you plot ? What is the x-axis ? y-axis ? and what does the color mean ? Can you also post the code that you used to calculate the spectrum and plotting ? Thank you.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, One thing confused me is that, we have $\sigma_1^x \sigma_{2}^x$, which is $4 \times 4$ matrix,  $\sigma_2^y \sigma_{3}^y$ is also a $4 \times 4$ matrix. When we put them into a $8 \times 8$ matrix, where to put them ? If we allow interaction between Spin 1 and Spin 3, then we will also have $\sigma_1^x \sigma_{3}^x$,  where to put this matrix in to the $8 \times 8$ matrix ?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I strongly disagree that it is clear that *"it is not feasible to solve the problem exactly"* -- for instance, at least without field this should be solvable by Bethe ansatz. There's plenty of problems where one can find simpler (e.g. transfer matrix formulation for classical 1D statmech) or even closed (e.g. Bethe ansatz) solutions. Ruling this out categorically would require a proof.

Comment: @david The Mod is because I took the chain to be a circle, i.e., periodic boundary conditions. You can of course consider other b.c.'s if you want. The axes denote $J_y$ and $J_z$, the color is the size of the gap (see the legend). I updated the code to include the method to generate the figure.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Yes absolutely, I should have specified that the problem is hard for *generic* systems. Integrable systems are the exception and for those, it is definitely true that there are methods that are infinitely better than the brute force approach. Bethe being the obvious example, which IIRC was precisely invented to solve the Heisenberg chain...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, what is IIRC ?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, thank you again. What does &@Sort[Eigenvalues[%] do in your code ?

Comment: For two spin system, I know that we can find the eigenvalue using raising and lowering operators. Can this raising and lowering operators method also be used to calculate eigenvalues for more than two spins ? @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I think that at least for h=0, the problem asked here is integrable. Thus, I would be careful to claim that the problem asked in this question is exponentially hard to solve.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Indeed as I said, $h=0$ is integrable and, historically, it was precisely this problem what lead Bethe to introduce his method. But $h\neq0$ is not integrable and no such methods are available.

Comment: @david IIRC means "if I recall correctly". `Sort` sorts the eigenvalues. As for &@, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, Thank you.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I thought Bethe introduced this for the Heisenberg model, not XYZ?